# I can't find the SQL Server 2005 Database Tuning Advisor

Tags: sql-server, database-tuning

I can't find the SQL Server 2005  Database Tuning Advisor on my computer. Is it something I needed to specifically choose when I installed SQL Server 2005?

I looked in All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and also in the C:Program Files Microsoft SQL Server directory and didn't see anything that could have been it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open SQL Management studio then go to the Tools menu up top. Its the second one from the top

Comment: Thanks. It was also not loaded on that machine. I was able to access it through All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -> Performance Tools on another machine as well as through ssms.